# AutoImporter no longer import my photos, after switching to iOS 10.2

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, image-capture

To automatically transfer photos from my iPhone 5S to a folder on my Mac (macOS 10.11.6), I had configured the macOS utility named AutoImporter.app.

**After upgrading my iPhone 5S from iOS 9.3 to iOS 10 (10.2), AutoImporter.app on my Mac continues to run upon connecting my iPhone to it using an USB cable. However, it quits immediately without importing any photos.**

This tool is very practical on a daily basis (it avoids going through applications such as "Photos.app". I don't use it. Why should I use an app to organize my photos?).

An idea, a solution? Thank you for your help.

*Just for your info : this is how I have configured autoimporter: very simply from Image Capture and what it should do when I connect my iPhone to my Mac using a USB cable (when it works correctly).*

[image: autoimporter dont work]
[image: autoimporter help]

Comment: And importing manually still works as usual?

Comment: @Phong Yes it does, so seems to be a problem with AutoImporter itself

Answer (score 3):

There might be multiple solutions to this:

#### Verify Auto Importer settings

1. Go into Finder
2. Hit <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>
3. Enter the following path: `/System/Library/Image Capture/Support/Application/`
4. Open up the `AutoImporter.app`
5. Hit <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to open up the settings
6. Verify, that everything is set up the way you want it to be.
7. Retry by reconnecting your phone.

#### Reset Auto Importer start

1. Open *Image Capture*
2. Set the *Connecting this iPhone opens:* option to something different then "Auto Importer", like Image Capture.
3. Reconnect your iPhone, see whether it opens Image Capture.
4. Then alter the setting back to "Auto Importer".
5. Reconnect your phone and see whether it works.

#### Delete Auto Importer Prefs and Cache

1. Get [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (Freeware) or an similar App, because it's hard to locate the cache for Auto Importer by hand.
2. Open up AppCleaner and drag the `AutoImporter.app` onto it.
3. AppCleaner will show you the pref and cache files associated with AutoImporter

   - `com.apple.AutoImporter.plist` in `~/Library/Preferences/`
   - `com.apple.AutoImporter` folder at `/var/folders/[…]/com.apple.AutoImporter/`
4. Delete the plist and the cache folder.
5. Restart AutoImporter.app (for me it auto quitted itself after the first start, so restart it once again).
6. Retry by reconnecting your phone.

Comment: While may have helped, it did not, still quits immediately without importing any photos

Comment: Thats unfortunate, I have another possible solution (see above) if you didn't already upgrade to Sierra and thus fixing it.

Comment: Already tried this and retried once more – still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

In order to import your iPhone's photos using Image Capture and AutoImporter you need to **disable iCloud Photo Library and My Photo Stream**.

### How to disable iCloud Photo Library

[image: iCloud Photo Library Setting]

On your iPhone

1. Go to **Settings** > **Photos** & Camera
2. Disable **iCloud Photo Library** and **My Photo Stream**.
3. Connect your iPhone to you laptop

Be aware that your photos won't be uploaded to iCloud any longer.

As long as your iPhone is unlocked you can import your photos from any computer that supports USB cameras.

Comment: The photos are on the phone (as seen on the Image Capture screenshot), so uploading to iCloud has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: This looked like a great answer, but I just checked my settings, and both of those things are already off, yet I'm still having this problem.  :(  Not down-voting, but a note in case others think they're the only ones not gaining success from this.

Comment: @lindes thank you for your feedback and for pointing that out. I'll have a look at it with another device.

Answer (score 1):

In my case : I update to macOS Sierra (just now) and this feature works again ! But your infos are good !

Comment: A solution, but only if there is a wish/option to update

Comment: OK, I have now the same bug with my new iPhone SE !
iPhone SE up to date iOS 10.3.1 ! Restore from my old iPhone 5S.

Comment: And you are on macOS Sierra?
I'm currently just creating my own AutoImporter using ImageCaptureCore framework

Comment: Yes Im on macOS Sierra (i add so detail below). So cool you make your own ! Do you use shell script or it's objective C / swift ?

Comment: Objective-C, also during development process I've understood that the problem is somewhere deeper: sometimes after connecting it is possible to see that there are photos on phone in Image Capture, but in most cases none are shown and they appear only if I make one more photo without disconnecting the phone

Answer (score 1):

Given AutoImporter.app is not really working at this time, here's a hacky alternative, but it's instant, fast, and automatic so in practice works nicely.

**Step 1:**

Install Dropbox for Mac. Log in with a Dropbox account, enable the 'Import' camera uploads feature, and set it to always run at startup. You do not need an account with extra storage, but the Internet will need to be on.

**Step 2:**

Create up an Automator script to watch the `~/Dropbox/Camera Uploads` folder for new files (i.e. a Dropbox auto import) and then immediately move/copy them into a folder of your choice (where you would normally prefer them auto imported).

Instructions:

- Open Automator.app and make sure a template isn't already open (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>).
- Create a new Automator workflow using the "Folder Action" template:

[image]

- In the title bar, select the folder you want to watch for new import items. Then drag the Action "Move Finder Items" from the library of actions into the workflow. (Find it via search or in list of 'Files & Folders'.) Choose the folder you want, for me I chose 'Google Drive' as I like to put it into my Google account by default.

[image]

(Optionally, you can copy - not move - the files using "Copy Finder items" Automator action so Dropbox can also upload it to the cloud anyway.)

- Then save the workflow with File > Save, choosing any name.
- The Automator script is now 'Live' in macOS 24/7, job done. To edit or delete it later, navigate to `~/Library/Services` to open to edit or just delete it.

**Result:**

Now, every time you connect the iPhone to the Mac, new photos or videos will be reliably imported into `~/Dropbox/Camera Uploads` and with your complete control using Automator services over how it's handled.

Enjoy.

*Attribution for this mini-guide where they have it auto Importing the items to macOS Photos app which is cool as well: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-11462*

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE APRIL 2017 :** 
I have now the same bug with my new iPhone SE !
iPhone SE up to date iOS 10.3.1 & Mac with macOS Sierra last version. New iPhone SE restored from my old iPhone 5S. Don't work at now ! It's a curious bug :

- iCloud Photo Library and My Photo Stream : disabled.
- Image Capture and AutoImporter.app pref and cache reseted !

What I can do ?

New (so strange infos) : When the iPhone is already connected to the Mac and I login (after logging out)

- If the iPhone is unlocked the import is automatic
- If the iPhone is locked I am prompted to unlock it, then the import is automatic

BUG INFO after import :

```
       Process:               AutoImporter [1184]
    Path:                  /System/Library/Image Capture/Support/Application/AutoImporter.app/Contents/MacOS/AutoImporter
    Identifier:            com.apple.AutoImporter
    Version:               6.7 (6.7)
    Build Info:            ImageCapture-1106000000000000~877
    Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:        ??? [1]
    Responsible:           AutoImporter [1184]
    User ID:               501

    Date/Time:             2017-04-28 23:26:35.849 +0200
    OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.4 (16E195)
    Report Version:        12
    Anonymous UUID:        


    Time Awake Since Boot: 1700 seconds

    System Integrity Protection: enabled

    Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

    Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
    Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

    Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
    Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
    Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

    Application Specific Information:
    Crashing on exception: -[NSThemeFrame(0x7f9cfc2046f0) lockFocus] failed with window=0x6100001ea300, windowNumber=-1, [self isHiddenOrHasHiddenAncestor]=0

    Application Specific Backtrace 1:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd465537b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffe944948d objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd465a082 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fffd60a1ce0 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fffd221d459 -[NSView lockFocus] + 247
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fffd221b59b -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 1159
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fffd221739a -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1748
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fffd2216cab -[NSWindow displayIfNeeded] + 230
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fffd2976d24 ___NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserver_block_invoke.6228 + 277
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fffd2216789 __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke + 454
    10  QuartzCore                          0x00007fffda0f4dc6 _ZN2CA11Transaction19run_commit_handlersE18CATransactionPhase + 46
    11  QuartzCore                          0x00007fffda1fe8f0 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 160
    12  QuartzCore                          0x00007fffda0f38a1 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fffd24f9b99 __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke.31 + 323
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd45eadd7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd45ead47 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd45cb789 __CFRunLoopRun + 873
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd45cb1c4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    18  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffd3b2cebc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
    19  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffd3b2ccf1 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
    20  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffd3b2cb26 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fffd20c7e24 _DPSNextEvent + 1120
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fffd284385e -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 2796
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fffd20bc7ab -[NSApplication run] + 926
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fffd20871de NSApplicationMain + 1237
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffe9d2e235 start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2

    Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd2426792 -[NSApplication _crashOnException:] + 109
    1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd24f9d1a __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke.31 + 708
    2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd45eadd7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd45ead47 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd45cb789 __CFRunLoopRun + 873
    5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd45cb1c4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffd3b2cebc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
    7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffd3b2ccf1 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
    8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffd3b2cb26 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd20c7e24 _DPSNextEvent + 1120
    10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd284385e -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 2796
    11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd20bc7ab -[NSApplication run] + 926
    12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd20871de NSApplicationMain + 1237
    13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffe9d2e235 start + 1

    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe9e5d44e __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f47502 _pthread_wqthread + 1023
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f470f1 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe9e5d44e __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f47695 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f470f1 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 3:: Dispatch queue: AutoDownloader Import Queue
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe9e55386 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9d10a77 _os_semaphore_wait + 16
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9d01891 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 103
    3   com.apple.ImageCaptureCore      0x00007fffd65c542a ICPerformBlockOnMainThread + 356
    4   com.apple.ImageCaptureCore      0x00007fffd65f351d -[ICMasterDeviceBrowser stop:] + 143
    5   com.apple.ImageCaptureCore      0x00007fffd65c1dad -[ICDeviceBrowser stop] + 137
    6   com.apple.AutoImporter          0x000000010da6f0e8 -[AppController removeDownloader:] + 135
    7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9d01524 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9cf88fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9d0e6f1 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 209
    10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9d01306 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1046
    11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9d07020 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 369
    12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9cfa6b5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 476
    13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9cfa48c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 99
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f47616 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f470f1 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe9e5d44e __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f47695 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f470f1 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe9e5d44e __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f47502 _pthread_wqthread + 1023
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f470f1 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe9e5d44e __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f47695 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f470f1 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe9e5d44e __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f47695 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f470f1 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 8:: com.apple.NSEventThread
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe9e5534a mach_msg_trap + 10
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe9e54797 mach_msg + 55
    2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd45cc4e4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
    3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd45cb971 __CFRunLoopRun + 1361
    4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd45cb1c4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd22152d2 _NSEventThread + 205
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f479af _pthread_body + 180
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f478fb _pthread_start + 286
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f47101 thread_start + 13

    Thread 9:: Dispatch queue: NSCGSDisableUpdates
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe9e5534a mach_msg_trap + 10
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe9e54797 mach_msg + 55
    2   com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffe60e632d _CGSReenableUpdateForConnectionSync + 99
    3   com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffe61b88c0 CGSUpdateManager::enable_update(unsigned long long) + 532
    4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9d01524 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9cf88fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9d0e9a0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 896
    7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9d01306 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1046
    8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9d07020 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 369
    9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9cfa6b5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 476
    10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffe9cfa48c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 99
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f47616 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f470f1 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 10:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe9e5d44e __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f47695 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe9f470f1 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
      rax: 0x00007f9cfd850a00  rbx: 0x00006180002409f0  rcx: 0x0000000000000001  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
      rdi: 0x000061800027d400  rsi: 0x0000000000000ab1  rbp: 0x00007fff52191400  rsp: 0x00007fff521913f0
       r8: 0x0000000008000100   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00007fffef5d0190  r11: 0x0000000000000dff
      r12: 0x00007fffd2cf102a  r13: 0x4043bd08b52c005d  r14: 0x00007fffe943b040  r15: 0x000061000013f360
      rip: 0x00007fffd2426792  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x00007f9cfd851808

    Logical CPU:     6
    Error Code:      0x00000000
    Trap Number:     6


    Binary Images:
           0x10da6d000 -        0x10da78ff3  com.apple.AutoImporter (6.7 - 6.7) <F374CF3B-DBA2-3E56-B400-F72D8B54230D> /System/Library/Image Capture/Support/Application/AutoImporter.app/Contents/MacOS/AutoImporter
           0x10f9f5000 -        0x10f9f5fff  com.apple.ICALogging (1.0 - 1) <7ADDA2E4-6834-34D4-AE3F-E38D177CA0A7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ICALogging.framework/ICALogging
           0x111149000 -        0x1112effff  GLEngine (14.0.16) <E67A2652-EEBB-38BF-9FF2-6C64ED0ABA9B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
           0x11132e000 -        0x111889ff7  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsGLDriver (10.24.45 - 10.2.4) <841A5F5A-0B40-3746-87EA-81F148645B9D> /System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsGLDriver
           0x111aa0000 -        0x111acafff  GLRendererFloat (14.0.16) <768ADC3B-C0E6-3936-801C-35990D62CAE7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources/GLRendererFloat.bundle/GLRendererFloat
           0x111af2000 -        0x111b6afff  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsMTLDriver (10.24.45 - 10.2.4) <D8034390-8A45-3A88-86D7-631B7076FD03> /System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsMTLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsMTLDriver
           0x11d75c000 -        0x11d799dc7  dyld (433.5) <8239D0D7-66F6-3C44-A77F-586F74525DA3> /usr/lib/dyld
        0x7fffcfb4a000 -     0x7fffd0397fff  com.apple.GeForceGLDriver (10.16.34 - 10.1.6) <E2F65916-324C-3FF3-933E-25670A3CF8B1> /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/GeForceGLDriver
        0x7fffd0398000 -     0x7fffd0c5dff3  libclh.dylib (4.0.3 - 4.0.3) <724139ED-ED81-39BE-A226-B080DD404719> /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/libclh.dylib
        0x7fffd0c5e000 -     0x7fffd0d6eff7  com.apple.GeForceMTLDriver (10.16.34 - 10.1.6) <6BABB0D8-05C7-3AF3-BB54-D86BD65C25A9> /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceMTLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/GeForceMTLDriver
        0x7fffd0d74000 -     0x7fffd0f35fff  com.apple.avfoundation (2.0 - 1187.36) <474E9FF4-4A97-3D48-8D4F-46FD3CADBBD6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation
        0x7fffd0f36000 -     0x7fffd0fd8ff7  com.apple.audio.AVFAudio (1.0 - ???) <7997D588-B542-3EBB-B822-D719C1114BB4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AVFAudio.framework/Versions/A/AVFAudio
        0x7fffd10a3000 -     0x7fffd10a3fff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <E559CE70-1A9A-3C5C-9FB7-C51FDF82F03C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
        0x7fffd10a4000 -     0x7fffd10bbffb  libCGInterfaces.dylib (331.5) <E0CA9D83-7F26-3D65-9249-F9231C1CB7DB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCGInterfaces.dylib
        0x7fffd10bc000 -     0x7fffd15d5feb  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - ???) <3992178B-0FF2-3B05-8830-6894BE8FD6D6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
        0x7fffd15d6000 -     0x7fffd1747ff3  libBLAS.dylib (1185.50.4) <4087FFE0-627E-3623-96B4-F0A9A1991E09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
        0x7fffd1748000 -     0x7fffd175cffb  libBNNS.dylib (15) <254698C7-7D36-3FFF-864E-ADEEEE543076> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
        0x7fffd175d000 -     0x7fffd1b53fef  libLAPACK.dylib (1185.50.4) <C35FFB2F-A0E6-3903-8A3C-113A74BCBCA2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
        0x7fffd1b54000 -     0x7fffd1b6afff  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1185.50.4) <345CAACF-7263-36EF-B69B-793EA8B390AF> 
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
        0x7fffd2e6c000 -     0x7fffd2e6cfff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (48 - 48) <847E54B5-DEA4-3B50-93CE-4FC67789F179> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
        0x7fffd2e6d000 -     0x7fffd2edbff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS (377 - 422.2) <012ACEE0-9A90-3998-8495-734E105117C0> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
        0x7fffd2f75000 -     0x7fffd30a4ff7  libFontParser.dylib (194.11) <635DF6EF-18DF-3D06-90AA-88C509B43068> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
        0x7fffd30a5000 -     0x7fffd30effff  libFontRegistry.dylib (196.4) <EA96AE47-3369-3DEA-BB82-98348ADBD85B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib

        0x7fffd576c000 -     0x7fffd5774ff3  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1230.50.1 - 1230.50.1) <2AD1B0E5-7214-37C4-8D11-A27C9CAC0F74> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
        0x7fffd5775000 -     0x7fffd58e1ff7  com.apple.LaunchServices (775.19 - 775.19) <1CF81B5F-BA1A-3FC6-B4F9-E0A319AE94D0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
        0x7fffd58e2000 -     0x7fffd5992ffb  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 1075.40) <F205A001-250D-3D9A-8375-0F7A834C46E6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
        0x7fffd5993000 -     0x7fffd59f2fff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (775.19 - 775.19) <724312AC-5CE8-333C-BC35-BC5AB1583D9A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
        0x7fffd59f3000 -     0x7fffd5a63fff  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <7A6DDA2B-03F1-3137-BA9E-1CC211973E26> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
        0x7fffd5a64000 -     0x7fffd5aa9ff7  com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList (38 - 38) <DA096678-93AB-3291-BDE2-482F1D544589> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SharedFileList.framework/Versions/A/SharedFileList
        0x7fffd5b32000 -     0x7fffd5c7eff3  com.apple.CoreText (352.0 - 544.12) <1ED17C4A-9E2D-3537-8C5F-FB675492A002> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
        0x7fffd5c7f000 -     0x7fffd5cb4ff3  com.apple.CoreVideo (1.8 - 235.3) <AC11D5FB-C77B-34F5-B942-F698E84C229F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
        0x7fffd5cb5000 -     0x7fffd5d26ffb  com.apple.framework.CoreWLAN (11.0 - 1200.31) <3A83EBE9-68C5-37DD-AD6F-AF4B37813480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework/Versions/A/CoreWLAN
        0x7fffd5e24000 -     0x7fffd5e29fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.7 - 2.7) <A4DCD470-D8EA-37E9-BDCA-A2B469754C12> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
        0x7fffd5fbb000 -     0x7fffd6361ff3  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1349.64) <49C8DA40-9E5B-33F9-B092-F50115B59E95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
        0x7fffd638d000 -     0x7fffd63beff7  com.apple.GSS (4.0 - 2.0) <6FADED0B-0425-3567-A75A-040C5A4638EB> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
        0x7fffd647e000 -     0x7fffd6521ffb  com.apple.Bluetooth (5.0.4 - 5.0.4f18) <00D257AA-283D-3395-B9B0-FEB70764080B> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/IOBluetooth
        0x7fffd6522000 -     0x7fffd65b7fff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1324.50.21) <BA7DC917-35A9-3D1B-BBEC-ADF4495A166D> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
        0x7fffd65b8000 -     0x7fffd65beffb  com.apple.IOSurface (159.6 - 159.6) <661BFCC0-85AB-3343-853E-3797932871D4> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
        0x7fffd65bf000 -     0x7fffd6610fff  com.apple.ImageCaptureCore (7.0 - 7.0) <22A35555-6025-3EB8-993B-B91141668C6A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageCaptureCore.framework/Versions/A/ImageCaptureCore
        0x7fffd6611000 -     0x7fffd6770fe7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.3.0 - 1599.7) <2BDE099C-94BA-390E-9CB5-6BE969532EB6> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
        0x7fffd6771000 -     0x7fffd6775fff  libGIF.dylib (1599.7) <B0D5A8F5-9DF3-33D7-B860-05C1CBF3C11E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
        0x7fffd6776000 -     0x7fffd6866ff7  libJP2.dylib (1599.7) <8AF4DA0A-7D10-3082-9523-FEA4F51E1568> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
        0x7fffd6867000 -     0x7fffd688affb  libJPEG.dylib (1599.7) <D6530D83-840B-360D-B444-C06FFF64DEEA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
        0x7fffd688b000 -     0x7fffd68b2ff7  libPng.dylib (1599.7) <EB2FC33D-A7CC-37C1-8A22-7D8069EB3FE8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
        0x7fffd68b3000 -     0x7fffd68b5ff3  libRadiance.dylib (1599.7) <FA599313-8434-3F68-B33B-A49B7B46B783> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
        0x7fffd68b6000 -     0x7fffd6904feb  libTIFF.dylib (1599.7) <1C2B6B4D-D77C-3F48-8D04-E5F4F2EAAECA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
        0x7fffd6a62000 -     0x7fffd766aff3  com.apple.JavaScriptCore (12603 - 12603.1.30.0.34) <42993DA4-E18A-3A41-86F8-23A6656273F9> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/JavaScriptCore
        0x7fffd766b000 -     0x7fffd7684ff7  com.apple.Kerberos (3.0 - 1) <B9D242EB-E325-3A21-9812-C77CBBFB0D51> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
        0x7fffd790d000 -     0x7fffd7913fff  com.apple.MediaAccessibility (1.0 - 97.1.1) <0BD82735-6644-37CE-B13D-8E7CC59A1752> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/Versions/A/MediaAcce
        0x7fffe9d62000 -     0x7fffe9d62ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (67) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
        0x7fffe9e66000 -     0x7fffe9eadfe7  libsystem_m.dylib (3121.6) <A790C9A5-DD24-32F5-8FD7-33BFCE79AC87> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
        0x7fffe9eae000 -     0x7fffe9eccff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (116.50.8) <48D1BBA3-914E-3C65-AF70-C33B4A1B5233> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
        0x7fffe9ecd000 -     0x7fffe9f26ffb  libsystem_network.dylib (856.50.56) <FDE14243-4328-3EFD-824C-C0D314D7B540> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
        0x7fffe9f27000 -     0x7fffe9f30ff3  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (563.50.32) <D5381DA9-529C-3588-BE16-A2245DE93423> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
        0x7fffe9f31000 -     0x7fffe9f3aff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (165.20.1) <B8160190-A069-3B3A-BDF6-2AA408221FAE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
        0x7fffe9f3b000 -     0x7fffe9f43fe7  libsystem_platform.dylib (126.50.8) <5940EAB7-84D6-34DC-9B38-111648B2B589> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
        0x7fffe9f44000 -     0x7fffe9f4eff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (218.51.1) <62A84A68-431D-3B54-A7B6-31367CCF2884> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
        0x7fffe9f4f000 -     0x7fffe9f52ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (592.50.47) <87A2327D-B7A1-3E4C-A85D-D3D9484003DB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
        0x7fffe9f53000 -     0x7fffe9f54ff3  libsystem_secinit.dylib (24.50.4) <F78B847B-3565-3E4B-98A6-F7AD40392E2D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
        0x7fffe9f55000 -     0x7fffe9f5cffb  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (532.50.47) <9CF6A47C-8343-3E85-9C27-A8D98E726A8B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
        0x7fffe9f5d000 -     0x7fffe9f70ff7  libsystem_trace.dylib (518.51.1) <E1D540D8-CC88-3901-92BA-FC4B802FE0E8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
        0x7fffe9f71000 -     0x7fffe9f76ffb  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <3D50D8A8-C460-334D-A519-2DA841102C6B> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
        0x7fffe9f77000 -     0x7fffe9fa0ff7  libxpc.dylib (972.50.27) <ABC45890-DA23-3A4A-B50B-1384BD4CBBDF> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

    External Modification Summary:
      Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
        task_for_pid: 0
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0
      Calls made by this process:
        task_for_pid: 0
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0
      Calls made by all processes on this machine:
        task_for_pid: 610
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0

    VM Region Summary:
    ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=319.9M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=319.9M(100%)
    Writable regions: Total=156.4M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=156.4M(100%)

                                    VIRTUAL   REGION 
    REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
    ===========                     =======  ======= 
    Accelerate framework               128K        2 
    Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
    CG backing stores                 1796K        4 
    CG image                            80K        9 
    CoreAnimation                       92K        9 
    CoreServices                        60K        2 
    CoreUI image data                 1896K       12 
    CoreUI image file                  292K        6 
    Image IO                            28K        3 
    Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
    MALLOC                           123.1M       64 
    MALLOC guard page                   48K       10 
    Memory Tag 242                      12K        2 
    Memory Tag 251                      12K        2 
    STACK GUARD                       56.0M       12 
    Stack                             13.1M       12 
    VM_ALLOCATE                         76K       14 
    __DATA                            38.7M      263 
    __GLSLBUILTINS                    2588K        2 
    __IMAGE                            528K        2 
    __LINKEDIT                       116.2M        9 
    __TEXT                           203.8M      263 
    __UNICODE                          556K        2 
    mapped file                       51.8M       12 
    shared memory                     16.4M       13 
    ===========                     =======  ======= 
    TOTAL                            627.2M      708 

    Model: MacBookPro11,3, BootROM MBP112.0138.B25, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.19f12
    Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
    Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, PCIe, 2048 MB
    Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
    Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
    AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 ()
    Bluetooth: Version 5.0.4f18, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
    Network Service: iPhone, Ethernet, en4
    Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512F, 500,28 GB
    USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
    USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
    USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
    USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
    USB Device: iPhone
    Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.1
```