# macOS Automator : is there an event for "iOS device connected"?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, automator

I am wondering about the presence of an event "iOS / iPhone device connected" in macOS Sierra Automator.

**I would like to launch an automatic import from photos, into specific folder on my mac.** (Indeed, the AutoImporter.app function of the Image Transfer app does not work with me, it's a unresolved BUG, please note iCloud disabled don't resolve it).

Thanks for your help and knowledge in Automator

Answer (score 1):

In order to import your iPhone's photos using Image Capture and AutoImporter you need to **disable iCloud Photo Library and My Photo Stream**.

### How to disable iCloud Photo Library

[image: iCloud Photo Library Setting]

On your iPhone

1. Go to **Settings** > **Photos** & Camera
2. Disable **iCloud Photo Library** and **My Photo Stream**.
3. Connect your iPhone to you laptop

Be aware that your photos won't be uploaded to iCloud any longer.

As long as your iPhone is unlocked you can import your photos from any computer that supports USB cameras.

---

Now you are able to import your photos with AutoImporter.app.

Comment: I know. But that don't work for me and many people. Seems its a bug. So we search other way.

Comment: See that : We talking about AutoImporter.app bug here : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271595/autoimporter-no-longer-import-my-photos-after-switching-to-ios-10-2